# Turn Based Combat System

Tags: python, class

I am trying to figure out a turn system that is reliant on a variable I am going to call `speed`. This variable will determine how many times out of the total of all `speed` between players. The number of players is subject to change, and so is their speed.

Say I have the following code.

```
class player(object):
    def __init__(self, id, speed):
        self.id = id # id is what player they are, id = 3 means player3
        self.speed = speed

players = [player(1, 4), player(2, 9), player(3, 6), player(4, 5)]
```

The total number of turns will be 24, which is all the speeds added together. Taking player3 for example, out of the predetermined 24 turns in the round, they will go 6 times.

The thing that makes this tricky is that I want these turns as separated as possible. The only thing separated each of player3's turns, will be the turns of other players.

The desired output is a list in order of the turns that will be taken of the player's `id`s. A simpler example is shown below along with the desired output.

```
class player(object):
    def __init__(self, id, speed):
        self.id = id # id is what player they are, id = 3 means player3
        self.speed = speed

players = [player(1, 2), player(2, 4), player(3, 6)]

# I'm calling the desired output turnList
>>turnList = [3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1] # potentially shortened to [3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1]
```

Another condition that isn't required is that the players will go in the order of their speed, notice in the example that player3 went first because their speed the highest, followed by player2, then player1.

The question I have is how do I get from the given list of players, and get an output of the player's `id` in turn order based on these conditions. To be as blunt as possible in asking, I want the code to get the desired output, turnList.

Comment: What exactly is your question about this?

Comment: @mkrieger1 How do I get a list of the player's ids based on speed. I currently have no way of getting from the list of players to the desired turnList.

Comment: Why is the output 3, 2, 3, 2, 1 and not 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, or 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3?

Comment: @ScottBoston The output is not `3, 2, 3, 2, 1` it is `3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1`, and I think the answer to your question is in my question. _The thing that makes this tricky is that I want these turns as separated as possible. The only thing separated each of player3's turns, will be the turns of other players._ Although I'm not particularly sure of based on how general your question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long-solved problem ... if you're a DungeonMaster.  Each of these is a speed.  Therefore, divide the entire period (call it a "round") into `N` time intervals, where `N` is the player's speed.  Then assign the player's turns to the middle of each intervals.  For instance, player 2 has 4 turns.  Divide the round into 4 equal intervals:

```
[0.00, 0.25]
[0.25, 0.50]
[0.50, 0.75]
[0.75, 1.00]
```

Assign the player's turn to the center of each interval:

```
[0.00, 0.25]    0.125
[0.25, 0.50]    0.375
[0.50, 0.75]    0.625
[0.75, 1.00]    0.875
```

... and there are your turn times for player 1.

Do likewise for all of the players, and make a list of tuples: `(turn_time, id)`:

```
(0.250, 1)
(0.750, 1)
(0.125, 2)
(0.375, 2)
(0.625, 2)
(0.875, 2)
(0.083, 3)
(0.250, 3)
(0.417, 3)
(0.583, 3)
(0.750, 3)
(0.917, 3)
```

Sort the list, and there's your schedule for the round.

Do note that you'll likely want to resolve conflicts in some other way: a simple sort will always give precedence to the player with the lower ID# -- players 1 and 3, in this case.

I trust that you can handle the algebra and coding from here.

Comment: Thank you, yes I can handle it from here.